# UnicodeEncodeError: Scraping data using Python and beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, csv, unicode, beautifulsoup, scrape

I am trying to scrape data from the PGA website to get a list of all the golf courses in the USA. I want to scrape the data and input into a CSV file. My problem is after running my script I get this error. Can anyone help fix this error and how I can go about extracting the data?

Here is the error message:

> File "/Users/AGB/Final_PGA2.py", line 44, in 
>   writer.writerow(row)
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in
>   position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Script Below;

```
import csv
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

courses_list = []
for i in range(906):      # Number of pages plus one 
    url = "http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page={}&searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0&course_type=both&has_events=0".format(i)
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data2=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-nothing"})

for item in g_data2:
    try:
          name = item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-title"})[0].text
          print name
    except:
          name=''
    try:
          address1=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-address"})[0].text
    except:
          address1=''
    try:
          address2=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-city-state-zip"})[0].text
    except:
          address2=''
    try:
          website=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-website"})[0].text
    except:
          website=''   
    try:
          Phonenumber=item.contents[1].find_all("div",{"class":"views-field-work-phone"})[0].text
    except:
          Phonenumber=''      

    course=[name,address1,address2,website,Phonenumber]

    courses_list.append(course)


with open ('PGA_Final.csv','a') as file:
          writer=csv.writer(file)
          for row in courses_list:
               writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to display properly? If you indent the whole thing 4 spaces it'll show as a code block instead of unformatted text.

Comment: I edited the post, awaiting approval.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551429/error-writing-data-to-csv-due-to-ascii-error-in-python/30551550#30551550

Comment: there are many issues in your code: 0. Indentation matters in Python, check `requests.get(url)` line 1. don't use bare `except:`, it may catch too much and hide bugs, add error logging for debugging 2. avoid the repetitive code, create a function instead. 3. Make sure you know what Python version you use: you should not see this error on Python 3

Answer (score 1):

You should not get the error on Python 3. Here's code example that fixes some unrelated issues in your code. It parses specified fields on a given web-page and saves them as csv:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4 # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

page = 905
url = ("http://www.pga.com/golf-courses/search?page=" + str(page) +
       "&searchbox=Course+Name&searchbox_zip=ZIP&distance=50&price_range=0"
       "&course_type=both&has_events=0")
with urlopen(url) as response:
    field_content = bs4.SoupStrainer('div', 'views-field-nothing')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, parse_only=field_content)

fields = [bs4.SoupStrainer('div', 'views-field-' + suffix)
          for suffix in ['title', 'address', 'city-state-zip', 'website', 'work-phone']]

def get_text(tag, default=''):
    return tag.get_text().strip() if tag is not None else default

with open('pga.csv', 'w', newline='') as output_file:
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for div in soup.find_all(field_content):
        writer.writerow([get_text(div.find(field)) for field in fields])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open ('PGA_Final.csv','a') as file:
          writer=csv.writer(file)
          for row in courses_list:
               writer.writerow(row)
```

Change that to:

```
with open ('PGA_Final.csv','a') as file:
          writer=csv.writer(file)
          for row in courses_list:
               writer.writerow(row.encode('utf-8'))
```

Or:

```
import codecs
....
with codecs.open('PGA_Final.csv','a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
          writer=csv.writer(file)
          for row in courses_list:
               writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You can also use [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open), which works like the regular `open` but also accepts an `encoding` kwarg.

Comment: I added another solution with your suggestion.

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode' for the first option

Comment: Any suggestion on how I can fix that?

Comment: I had `import codes` instead of `import codecs`, that should fix the problem. The second error is because `row` is another list of its own, so you'll have to create a loop for it as well. I didn't know that since you didn't have data sample.

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after importing the right library.

Comment: can you provide a sample script to making it into a loop

Comment: It's to hard provide the right code without seeing the data. Which version of python are you using and what type of error were you getting when importing codecs?

Comment: I am still getting the same error after using the one with codecs                  This is the error. UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: My data is take from the PGA.com website and I use python 3.4